# Dell Latitude e6540 unable to be increased past 1366 x 768

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, resolution, dell-latitude

I have been messing around with the laptop all day trying to change the resolution.  1366x768 is the smallest it allows and I typically like something closer to the 1920x1080 or at the very least 1600x whatever.

The graphics card is showing up as an Intel(R) HD Graphics 4600 but the monitor keeps showing up as Generic PnP Monitor.  I tried downloading various drivers off the dell site hoping one of them would work but I have had no luck

Comment: are you sure your laptop's screen resolution is higher than 1366x768?

Comment: that is as high as it will go.  It ranges from the 1366x760 to 800x600.

Comment: I'm not asking about the current available resolutions. I'm asking about the native panel resolution. If the native panel resolution is only 1366x768, it's not possible to choose a higher resolution for it.

Answer (score 2):

The resolution for that screen doesn't go any higher....

The specs clearly state: `15.6inch HD (1366x768) Anti-Glare LED`

[Specs](http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/latitude-e6540-laptop/pd?oc=sml6540w7p202&model_id=latitude-e6540-laptop)

Answer (score 0):

I have an e6420 and use an external monitor. I'm able to get higher resolution. You can also use both laptop screen and external monitor as dual monitor.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the driver or the graphics card. I use a Dell Latitude E5470 with 2 wide monitors hooked to a docking station and they both go without any problem with a 1920x1080 resolution. The laptop display can't go higher than 1366x768.